# Excel: Dependent drop-down + calculations through multiple sheets (with different columns position)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

What I am trying to do is doing some calculations (Main sheet) through different sheets with similar structure in the same Workbook, so once when I pick something from drop-down it should calculate for instance Total Tonnage through all the sheets and it will give me the results on main page (J4).

There are more fields to calculate, but I just need another idea or opinion how to proceed..The sheets are similar but not consistent, combined numbers/text, just some random data actually.

[image: Data]

Here are the formulas what I have been using on Column J4 - J7

J4 `=IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$2&" ";SUM(tbl_CS1B[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$4&" ";SUM(tbl_CS2A[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$7&" ";SUM(tbl_CS3E[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$8&" ";SUM(tbl_CS3F[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$9&" ";SUM(tbl_CS3G[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$10&" ";SUM(tbl_CS3H[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$11&" ";SUM(tbl_CS3K[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$12&" ";SUM(tbl_CS3P[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$15&" ";SUM(tbl_CS7A[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$16&" ";SUM(tbl_CS7B[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$17&" ";SUM(tbl_CS7D[Menge '[t']]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$18&" ";SUM(tbl_CS7E[Menge '[t']]);"")))))))))))`)

J5 `=IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$2&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS1B[Charge];tbl_CS1B[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$4&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS2A[Charge];tbl_CS2A[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$7&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3E[Charge];tbl_CS3E[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$8&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3F[Charge];tbl_CS3F[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$9&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3G[CS3G Charge];tbl_CS3G[CS3G Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$10&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3H[Charge];tbl_CS3H[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$11&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3K[Charge];tbl_CS3K[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$12&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3P[Charge];tbl_CS3P[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$15&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS7A[Charge];tbl_CS7A[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$16&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS7B[Charge];tbl_CS7B[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$17&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS7D[Charge];tbl_CS7D[Charge]));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$18&" ";SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(tbl_CS7E[Charge];tbl_CS7E[Charge]));""))))))))))))`

J6 `=IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$2&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS1B[Rohstoff-Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS1B[Rohstoff-Charge];tbl_CS1B[Rohstoff-Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$4&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS2A[Rohware Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS2A[Rohware Charge];tbl_CS2A[Rohware Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$7&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS3E[Rohstoff-Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3E[Rohstoff-Charge];tbl_CS3E[Rohstoff-Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$8&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS3F[Rohstoff-Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3F[Rohstoff-Charge];tbl_CS3F[Rohstoff-Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$9&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS3G[Rohware Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3G[Rohware Charge];tbl_CS3G[Rohware Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$10&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS3H[Rohrware Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3H[Rohrware Charge];tbl_CS3H[Rohrware Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$11&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS3K[Rohstoff-Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3K[Rohstoff-Charge];tbl_CS3K[Rohstoff-Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$12&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS3P[Rohstoff-Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS3P[Rohstoff-Charge];tbl_CS3P[Rohstoff-Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$15&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS7A[Rohstoff-Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS7A[Rohstoff-Charge];tbl_CS7A[Rohstoff-Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$16&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS7B[Rohstoff-Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS7B[Rohstoff-Charge];tbl_CS7B[Rohstoff-Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$17&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS7D[Rohware Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS7D[Rohware Charge];tbl_CS7D[Rohware Charge]&""));IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$18&" ";SUMPRODUCT((tbl_CS7E[Rohstoff-Charge]<>"")/COUNTIF(tbl_CS7E[Rohstoff-Charge];tbl_CS7E[Rohstoff-Charge]&""));""))))))))))))`

J7 `=IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$2&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS1B[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$4&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS2A[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$7&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS3E[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$8&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS3F[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$9&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS3G[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$10&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS3H[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$11&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS3K[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$12&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS3P[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$15&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS7A[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$16&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS7B[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$17&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS7D[Faß]);IF($A$4=Calculation!$A$18&" ";COUNTA(tbl_CS7E[Faß]);""))))))))))))`

So, as you can see it works but the formulas are kilometers long. Does anyone can help with any other solution(s) or approaches to solve similar things through whole workbook?

My WB is formatted as a table from Power Query which gives me more possibilties, like Pivot tables and so on. But I would like to have those infos spilled on one page not on XY pages, like one pivot sheet for one material and so on..

Can that be achieved using INDIRECT function or some other combination?

I am using Office 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nested IFs, you can use MATCH & CHOOSE, so your formula in J4 would be:

`=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(LEFT($A$4,LEN($A$4)-1),{Calculation!$A$2,Calculation!$A$4,Calculation!$A$7,Calculation!$A$8,Calculation!$A$9,Calculation!$A$10,Calculation!$A$11,Calculation!$A$12,Calculation!$A$15,Calculation!$A$16,Calculation!$A$17,Calculation!$A$18},0),SUM(tbl_CS1B[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS2A[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS3E[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS3F[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS3G[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS3H[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS3K[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS3P[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS7A[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS7B[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS7D[Menge '[t']]),SUM(tbl_CS7E[Menge '[t']])),"")`

or even further reduce it using INDIRECT:

`=IFERROR(SUM(INDIRECT(CHOOSE(MATCH(LEFT($A$4;LEN($A$4)-1);{Calculation!$A$2;Calculation!$A$4;Calculation!$A$7;Calculation!$A$8;Calculation!$A$9;Calculation!$A$10;Calculation!$A$11;Calculation!$A$12;Calculation!$A$15;Calculation!$A$16;Calculation!$A$17;Calculation!$A$18};0);tbl_CS1B;tbl_CS2A;tbl_CS3E;tbl_CS3F;tbl_CS3G;tbl_CS3H;tbl_CS3K;tbl_CS3P;tbl_CS7A;tbl_CS7B;tbl_CS7D;tbl_CS7E)&"[Menge '[t']]"));"")`

Comment: It drops me an error on Calculation...here in Germany when it is a range {1,0.1} it has to be like this {1\0\1}..but it doesnt also work...

Comment: In my first formula I forgot to replace `, ` to `;`

Comment: Saw that but that aint a big deal. I still didnt manage to solve it using your functions. By "lookup_array" in Match {Calc...} somehow doesnt want to reference. Will report as soon as I get something. Thx anyways